# update existing model in DB

Tags: python, django

Hi every one I have an issue I want to update a specific model in the db like I want the user to
 change their phone number and picture...etc specific one not all the model and I am unable to do that in views.py, below is my code, can help pls?

models.py:

```
    # Create your models here.


    PHONE_REGEX = '^[0-9]*$'


    class Profile(AbstractUser):
        phone_number = models.CharField(
            max_length=14,
            help_text='Optional',
            blank=True,
            validators=[
                RegexValidator(
                    regex=PHONE_REGEX,
                    message=
                    'phone number must be only digit and from 10 to 14 digits only',
                    code='invalid-phone number'),
                MinLengthValidator(10)
            ])
        picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='upload/', blank=True, default=False)
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=254,
                                  unique=True,
                                  help_text='Required, pls enter a valid Email')
```

forms.py:

```
 class Change_pic_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('picture', )
```

Views.py 
here snippet of it

```
@login_required
def Change_picture(request):
    instance = Profile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
    form = Change_pic_form(request.POST or None, instance=instance)
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.save()
        return redirect('change_pic')
    else:
        form = Change_pic_form(instance=instance)
    context = {
        'picture': instance.picture,
        'form': form,
        'instance': instance,
    }
    return render(request, 'account/change_picture.html', context)
```

will maybe I didn't make it clear sorry for that, my site work OK I have login ,sign up ...etc, what I meant is I have user profile page where user can see his info and I want the user if he want to update his info like phone number , picture...etc

Comment: Can you please share views.py code in question?

Comment: ok i will share it

Comment: Now, you want to update only those particular fields which will be submitted from Change_pic_form,  right?

Comment: First of all please change the variable name `instance` because at two different place you gave same variable name `instance`

Comment: yes I want to update particular fields, in this function is the picture field, for variable name no issue will change it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run first `makemigrations` command

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
```

It will create migration file for all updated field in model and you can see it in migrations folder of that specific app.

Then you have to migrate that specific migration file...
For example your required model's migration file is `0002_auto_20170808_2327` then run below command

```
python manage.py migrate <app_name> 0002_auto_20170808_2327
```

Comment: my site works fine can you check what I edited on this question, thanks for help

Comment: Ok let me check @yazan_bader.

Answer (score 0):

You have your model and form, now you need to render your form in your template.
Read [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/) from documents to understand how to render a form in template and handle form submission in view.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anybody helped, I found the solution as for image or file you have to write in view
request.FILES and in your form that inside the template enctype="multipart/form-data" 
its work fine now.

Views.py

```
def Change_picture(request, pk):
    prof = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Change_pic_form(request.POST,
                               request.FILES,
                               instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your Picture updated successfully')
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = Change_pic_form(instance=request.user)
    return render(request, 'account/change_picture.html', {
        'prof': prof,
        'form': form
    })
```

the Template

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <br />
            {{ form.as_p }}
            <button type="submit">Change!</button>
        </form>
```